# Django admin: ¿cómo agregar la suma de todos los registros de un modelo?

Tags: python, django

Estoy creando una aplicación de contabilidad. Creé el modelo para las transacciones de la siguiente manera:

```
Transacciones()
    consumidor
    monto
    tipo_monto
    fecha
    comentario
```

En el admin hice que se muestren todas las columnas y también los filtros por cada columna, pero necesito que en una fila nueva se agregue el total de los montos de las transacciones.

¿Hay algún método de agregar este tipo de cosas en el admin?. Agregar un `Count` por ejemplo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Respondiendo a tu pregunta:

> ¿Hay algún método de agregar este tipo de cosas en el admin?

Si.

---

Lo que tienes que hacer primero es sobreescribir el método [`ModelAdmin.changelist_view`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_changelist), lo que necesitas es un `Sum`, no un `Count`:

**admin.py:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.db.models import Sum
from .models import Transacciones

class TransaccionesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        total = Transacciones.objects.aggregate(total=Sum('monto'))['total']
        context = {
            'total': total,
        }
        return super(TransaccionesAdmin, self).changelist_view(request, extra_context=context)

admin.site.register(Transacciones, TransaccionesAdmin)
```

Necesitas también [sobreescribir el template del admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates), esto lo puedes lograr copiando el template de la ruta `contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_list.html` y pegándola en la ruta de tu proyecto `templates/admin/nombre_app/transacciones/`.

Solo queda mostrar el resultado de `total` en el template y eso lo consigues mostrando como lo harías en cualquier otro template.

**templates/admin/nombre_app/transacciones/change_list.html:**

```
...
{% block content %}
   ...
   {{ total }}
   ...
{% endblock %}
...
```

Comment: Muchas gracias César, es justo lo que buscaba. ¿Esto me servirá por ejemplo si filtro por consumidor también?

Comment: @juanmuñoz esto solo te muestra el total general, es un poco complicado realmente conseguir lo que quieres ya que podrías aplicar algún filtro y recuerda también que el admin está paginado, mi respuesta solo te da una guía de cómo pasar el total al template del admin. Si necesitas hacer otras cosas puedes crear nuevas preguntas

Comment: Ok, entiendo... solo era por saber. Igualmente me sirve harto tu respuesta. Gracias denuevo.

Comment: @juanmuñoz de nada! Si te sirvió no olvides marcarla como aceptada al lado izquierdo de mi respuesta, de lo contrario permanecerá como no solucionada

Comment: Creo que no se necesita sobre escribir ese método, basta con que crees una función adicional que haga la suma y la coloque en la lista, no me acuerdo como se llama, pero en general sirve para muchas cosas, contadores, imágenes, etc.